# bazel build wildcards with suffix

Tags: bazel

I have some bazel rules like so:

```
//a/b/c:foo_x
//a/b/c:foo_y
//a/b/d:bar_x
//a/b/d:bar_y
//a/b/e/f/g:qux_x
//a/b/e/f/g:qux_y
```

Is there a way to say I want to build all rules with the "_x" suffix? I know that Bazel supports wildcards such as `//a/...` but I would like greater control over what exactly I am building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a combination of `query` and `grep`.

```
$ bazel build $(bazel query //a/b/... | grep -E ":.+_x")
```